# Python - problem plotting the Fourier transform of non periodic values

Tags: python, fft

I am having trouble plotting the fourier transform of a data series. I have measurements of something oscillating, my values look like that (x  axis is time, 10 seconds, y is some kind of acceleration):

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atGb0.png)

Then I use this function to do the fourier transform :

```
def plot_magnitude_spectrum(signal, title, sr):
    ft = np.fft.fft(signal)
    magnitude_spectrum = np.abs(ft)
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(18,5))
    frequency = np.linspace(0, sr, len(magnitude_spectrum))
    plt.plot(frequency, magnitude_spectrum)
    plt.xlabel("frequencies")
    plt.title(title)
    plt.show()
    
    
plot_magnitude_spectrum(normes, "normes", 10.5)
```

signal is the list of my measures, sr is sampling rate (I have 10.5 measures every seconds).
It gives me this graph :

[graphfourier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfzDt.png)

I'm trying to find the frequency of oscillation, but I feel like I'm doing it wrong. Was the FFT done incorrectly?

Comment: The first term is a constant and represents the average value of the signal. Since the average value of your original signal is quite large, it's not surprising that the constant term is also large.

Comment: Look up Gibbs' phenomenon.  Fourier transform implicitly takes the signal to be periodic, so imagine stacking the signal side by side -- there will be sharp differences at the boundaries, and therefore lots of power at small frequency.  Try your code on a signal you understand like a sin wave to make sure it works correctly.

Comment: Look into window functions, and consider cropping your data.